# How can I version control my projects' cron jobs?

Tags: git, version-control, cron, fabric

I have a bunch of projects that I push to a server with git and fab. They're a load of Django sites. Some of these sites have cron jobs.

I would like to be in a situation where I can:

- Manage the site's cron jobs by editing a file locally and running  a fab command (eg `fab save deploy` as I currently do)
- Have new jobs get installed remotely (only) and replace any old jobs (I don't want clone jobs each time)
- Keep the same highly customisable time settings. Not all my issues can be solved by @hourly.

What's the best way to approach this?

---

I am aware of [How do you deploy cron jobs to production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603034/how-do-you-deploy-cron-jobs-to-production) but the focus there seems to be about hacking the cronning into the fabric script and (at least in the answers) there's no consideration that there might be more than one project that needs cron jobs per user.

I'm after something that is stored in the VCS (I don't push my fabfile to git - and it's shared between all my projects) that will work alongside other jobs in crontab. It's no good if ProjectA and ProjectB overwrite each other's jobs each time I deploy.

Comment: I'm not sure if this might help, but have you though using puppet, and running puppet locally in stand alone mode? You could have a puppet module with all the configuration of your cron jobs and puppet will be responsible from inserting, updating or removing them from cron. Obviously, the puppet modules will be in your git repo with the rest of the code.

Comment: @Augusto The problem with that approach is similar to just using fabric. I *could* have fabric open a cron file (stored in git) and have it pump out the contents into the remote crontab ***but*** how do I make that process compatible with multiple projects? I can't just keep appending to the crontab or I'll have a million duplicate jobs.

Comment: Oli, I don't know fabric. Puppet doesn't insert duplicate crontabs, as it gives each entry an id (which is formatted as a comment above the entry). So as long as someone doesn't go on the box and removes that comment, puppet won't insert a duplicate and can even remove them if they are not needed anymore. I just realised that puppet doesn't fill your first point, but maybe you can write something that does the same thing as puppet, but remotely.

Comment: here's a script that'll convert your existing crons to puppet markup: https://shtuff.it/article/28/Convert-existing-crontab-for-use-with-puppet

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a fan of editing the crontab or per-user cron jobs; anyone editing the `crontab` can mess up your deployment. Instead, I create scripts that go into `/etc/cron.$interval` which allows me to deploy them with [Puppet](https://puppet.com/docs/open-source-puppet) (see the [cron type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/cheatsheet_core_types.html#cron)) or a simple `cp` command.

So if I need a script that runs once per day, I either put that into `$project/cron/cron.daily/$project` if I install without Puppet.

Alternatively, if you really need to merge crontabs, you should add a header and footer to each script, so it's easy to see where some part of the crontab comes from. The header/footer also allows you do automatically add/remove each script.

You should never replace the whole crontab because one day, someone will manually edit it. The edit will work until you deploy again at which time it will suddenly fail silently.

Answer (score 4):

So here's my best idea so far:

- All my projects live in `/web/project_name/`
- Any project that needs cronjobs sticks them in `/web/project_name/cron`
- On deploy, fab runs the following on the server:

  ```
  find /web/ -maxdepth 2 -name cron | xargs cat | crontab
  ```

This munges any cron files it finds in `/web/` and stuffs them in the crontab for my user. Better yet, if I have project independent jobs I want running, I can stick them in `/web/cron` and they'll go at the top of the resulting crontab.

Comment: Piping to crontab like that won't work. It needs a `-` but also it won't get installed after setting the content. I've found out, and recalled, that the hard way a few times.

Comment: @Morgan That's odd because it does work locally. Perhaps they've put something into the later versions to read from `stdin`

Comment: More than that, it does get installed into the user's crontab. Everything I've posted works on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I've seen it fill the contents of the user's crontab, but not "install " it, in that I've commented out things, and had them continue to execute until I've `crontab -e`'d the users stuff. If that works that's nice to have. Perhaps it's newer than what I've seen, or ubuntu magic stuff?