# Best way to version control a crontab file?

Tags: git, cron, centos6

I need to simplify management and implement a Git-based version control method for a crontab file on a server running CentOS 6.3. The crontab file in question is a user crontab that contains 100 or so jobs to automate ticket creation in a custom ticketing system derived from MantisBT. The goal is to store the cron jobs in a text file in a Git repo, and use a Jenkins project to push the file to a remote server and deploy the most recent crontab file. Is this a reasonable and effective way to manage a crontab file for an organization? Have you accomplished the same goal in a different way or have any recommendations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I version control my projects' cron jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509774/how-can-i-version-control-my-projects-cron-jobs)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your project in a Docker container, you could store cron file in your project, which is on GitHub or any other VCS.

Then in your Dockerfile, you can move cron file to the correct location in the container's file system.

In my project, I'm executing a shell script in Dockerfile, which is moving the
file:

```
if [ "$ENV" = "LIVE_SERVER" ]; then
    cp /home/project/project-name/crontab /etc/cron.d/commands;
fi;
```

On top of this, you need to set up Jenkins to build your project every time there is a new commit on the default branch.